# Dropoff location nickname not shown on Uber's Android app

Tags: android, uber-api

I'm using a standard deeplink to connect my app to Uber. When I'm transferred to the Uber app, the pickup and dropoff locations are shown but without the nicknames; just shows "Pickup Location" and "Dropoff Location"

This is the deeplink I'm using.

```
uri = "uber://?action=setPickup&client_id=X1gG3-qhdso7kj2beCiExF1VqGsSAi&pickup[latitude]=" + currentLocationLat + "&pickup[longitude]=" + currentLocationLng + "&dropoff[latitude]=" + destinationLat + "&dropoff[longitude]=" + destinationLng + "&dropoff[nickname]=" + addressName;
```

I've tried the same link on iOS and I've even used the same standard deeplink example on Uber Developers website and I still get the same result

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pickup=my_location` to make your deeplink simpler. I created a JSBin that works for me on Android and iOS with the newest Uber app: [Sample Deeplink](https://jsbin.com/zizuxiwili/1/edit?html,output)

I'd assume that the issue with the nickname is URL encoding. It's not obvious from your code sample if you encode the nickname. [Here are details for the URLEncoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).